# Latitude Does Not Work On Dock

Tags: dell, dock

So, I have a new Latitude E7470 and Ubuntu runs just fine on it. However once I put it on the dock it locks up and I have to hard shut it down.

Thoughts? 
[Here is my dock.](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=6099&l=en&sku=331-6307)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem disabling all displays when connecting and disconnecting from the dock.

I did this by using ARandR to make shell scripts for my different monitor configurations. I make one for just the laptop screen, one for my docked monitors, and one for no screens at all.

This solution also solves the problem where sometimes the correct monitor configuration is not automatically applied.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arise on hotplug connecting to external display. It's a known bug: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95498. Try to update core to 4.6 version. It's works for me.

You can do this as follows:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_%you_system_architecture%.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_%you_system_architecture%.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```